# Definition of MSO_1 for graph structures

Tags: model-checking

What is the proper definition of MSO$_1$?

MSO$_1$ is also called the one-sorted MSO. In contrast, in MSO$_2$, the two-sorted MSO, first order variables and set variables are allowed to be of two sorts -- vertex (set) or edge (set).

**Why not define MSO$_1$ as the fragment of MSO without any edge variables or edge set variable?** (that is, there is only one sort)

Instead, it is usually defined as the fragment of MSO without edge set quantification [some authors say quantification over sets of edges; it is ambiguous whether quantification over $E(G)$ is allowed]. Most authors explicitly state that quantification over $E(G)$ is allowed. But some authors such as Langer et. al. forbid quantification over $E(G)$ (see quote below).

I think my definition and the definition by Langer are actually same because we can express edge variables by vertex sets instead (eg: $\exists S\ \exists a\ \exists b\ ( a\neq b \wedge \forall c (c\in S\implies c=a \vee c=b) )$. Or am I mistaken?

**Details**

Here is a quote from *Practical algorithms for MSO model-checking on tree-decomposable graphs* by Langer et. al. (emphasis mine)

> Every variable $x$, $X$ is said to have a type tp($x$), tp($X$) $\in \{1,2\}$ denoting whether it refers to
>   vertices (tp($x$) = 1), edges (tp($x$) = 2), vertex sets (tp($X$) = 1),
>   or edge sets (tp($X$) = 2), respectively. The formulas of MSO$_2$ are
>   strings that are obtained from finitely many applications of
>   the following rules:
>
> 1. If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are individual variables with tp($x_1$ ) = tp($x_2$ ),
>      then $x_1$ = $x_2$ is a formula.
> 2. If $x_1$ , $x_2$ are individual variables with tp($x_1$ ) = tp($x_2$ ) = 1,
>      then adj($x_1$ , $x_2$ ) is a formula.
> 3. If $x_1$ , $x_2$ are individual variables with tp($x_1$ ) = 1 and
>      tp($x_2$ ) = 2, then inc($x_1$ , $x_2$ ) is a formula.
> 4. If $x$ is an individual variable and $X$ is a set variable with
>      tp($x$) = tp($X$), then $x\in X$ is a formula.
> 5. If $\phi$ is a formula then $\neg\phi$ is a formula.
> 6. If $\phi_1, \cdots, \phi_k$ are formulas then $(\phi_1\vee \cdots \vee \phi_k)$ and $(\phi_1\wedge \cdots \wedge \phi_k)$
>      are formulas.
> 7. If $\phi$ is a formula and $x$ is an individual variable then $\exists x\phi$ and $\forall x\phi$ are formulas.
> 8. If $\phi$ is a formula and $X$ is a set variable then $\exists X\phi$ and $\forall X\phi$ are formulas.
>
> If the formulas in 8 use edge set variables (tp($X$) = 2), we
>   call this quantification an edge set quantification. .......... MSO without
>   quantification over sets of edges, i.e., with **quantification over
>   sets of vertices only is called MSO$_1$** or one-sorted MSO.

Comment: What is "Langer et al"?  The standard reference for this area is the book "Graph Structure and Monadic Second-Order Logic, a Language Theoretic Approach" by Bruno Courcelle and Joost Engelfriet.

Comment: @Gamow I know. *Practical algorithms for MSO model-checking on tree-decomposable graphs* by Langer et. al. is a recent survey which is more approachable for people like me without a good background in language theory. I couldn't find such a short definition in the book.

Comment: Even simpler, you can simulate a quantifier over $E(G)$ by two quantifiers over $V(G)$. I guess the choice whether to include a first-order sort for $E(G)$ is just a matter of convenience.

Comment: I should add that the two approaches are equivalent for *simple* graphs. If you study graphs that may have multiple edges, then an $E(G)$ sort becomes indispensable.